# Twitter like buttons hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I want to know how to achieve Twitter like link control.

I mean when you're on their tweet page and when you hover over the tweets, there are links to reply, delete and favorite, and they disappear when you are not hovering it.

I don't know what keywords to search for.

Comment: ["html hover menu"](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+hover+menu) provides only about 7.7 *million* results. Maybe you'll find something there.

Comment: That is done with javascript.  There is absolutely nothing complicated about it.  Get yourself firebug installed on Firefox, and inspect the page and learn how they're doing it by investigating the page.  Most website interactivity that is not flash is done with a combination of dhtml and ajax... both buzzwords that describe clientside javascript code with the occasional use of ajax to call serverside scripts that return data.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart duh i was searching using other keyword..thx!

Comment: @gview Twitter does it with CSS.

Comment: I went to http://twiter.com as your question title suggests and was shocked to see their site was down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure CSS3

http://jsbin.com/evebij/2/edit

```
  <div>TWeeeet, tweeeet, tweet! ok , hover me now...
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="tweetLink">Share</a>
    <a href="#" class="tweetLink">Replay</a> 
    <a href="#" class="tweetLink">Add to Favourite</a> 
  </div>
```

```
.tweetLink {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0.2s linear, opacity 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0.2s linear, opacity 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: visibility 0.2s linear, opacity 0.2s linear;
}

div:hover .tweetLink {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: your example not working

Comment: @slyxar if you have an older IE... install some other browser :)